# How to fix Error:  could not access file "$libdir/librouting"?

Tags: pgrouting, mac

I am trying to run the sql file of pgrouting-> routing_core.sql in mac. However it displays the following error

```
psql:routing_core.sql:32: Error:  could not access file "$libdir/librouting": No such file or directory
```

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something went wrong when you compiled pgRouting as the libraries are not where they should be.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the CMakeCache.txt in the pgrouting folder and update the line which contains POSTGRESQL_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib.

After you execute the command cmake -DWITH_TSP=ON -DWITH_DD=ON and the lib librouting.so is copied to the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

Its installation issue. You didn't copy the dll files. You should check the installation instructions because different versions of pgrouting are installed differently. If I remember correctly, these are 3 files that you missed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with mac, but check the following things.

1. library(librouting.so) exists. (In my environment, "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.3/lib/librouting.so").
2. check "otool -L librouting.so" result. (In my environment, "/usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (...), /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (...), /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (...))

Comment: I don't remember the link where I got this, but I need to change $libdir/librouting to something else with absolute path. I don't have the link but the issue is fixed. Thanks everyone for your time and suggestions :)