# Pgrouting can't find postgresql (on Mac)

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I've installed both postgreSQL 9.0 and postgreSQL 9.1 on my mac, using binaries from http://www.kyngchaos.com. I also have postgis 1.5 installed.

I tried to install pgrouting, again using binaries from aforementioned website, but when I ran the core sql it gave the Error: could not access file “$libdir/librouting ([How to fix Error:  could not access file "$libdir/librouting"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26507/how-to-fix-error-could-not-access-file-libdir-librouting)) error.
So, instead I tried to build it from the source. but now when I run: cmake . , I get" -- PostgreSQL not found.
FATALERROR Please check your PostgreSQL installation" 
I tried to append it to path using "export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/pgsql-9.0/bin""
but it still didn't work.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

P.s. I should mention that I want to tell the system to install pgrouting for postgresql 9.0 and NOT 9.1 version.